# If? for Vlookup

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I don't know if this is even possible I am going to try to explain it the best I can, I don't know if the "IF" function is the correct thing to use here...

I want to Vlookup From a list in Column A but what I want to look up is dependent on what is in Column B

I don't know how to put this in a formula or even if you can:

If B3=R then =VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet1!$B:$R,11,false) If B2=L then =VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet2!$B:$R,11,false)

Is this possible? Any suggestions how to approach it, is there a better function that I don't know of yet? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
If (B3="R" , VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet1!$B:$R,11,false) , VLOOKUP(C3,Sheet2!$B:$R,11,false))
```

This is going to work if you have only 2 options in B3: R or L